# ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'globacom'@'localhost' to database 'avi_globacomglobacom_data4.sql'

Tags: mysql

I had created the database with the name globacom

```
  create database globacom;
```

and grant all the permissions as

```
    grant all on globacom.* to 'globacom'@'localhost' identified by 'globacom';
```

after this I have looged in using this credentials

```
       mysql -u globacom -pglobacom
```

when I import the .sql file  using this

```
    source E:\ravi_globacom\globacom_data4.sql
```

I am getting an error as

```
 ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'globacom'@'localhost' to database 'avi_globacomglobacom_data4.sql'
```

please anyone can help me.

Comment: Please help me it is very important for me

Comment: DO not cross-post! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590120/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-globacomlocalhost-to-database-a

Comment: Ok.Please help me.

Comment: Try `source E:/ravi_globacom/globacom_data4.sql`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use forward slashes for paths, even on Windows. The `mysql` command line is interpreting the sequence `\r` as a [`connect`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) command and things blow up. (This quite visible in the error message: `database 'avi_globacomglobacom_data4.sql'`.)

So try:

```
source E:/ravi_globacom/globacom_data4.sql
```

Or don't use `source`, but shell/cmd redirection instead:

```
mysql -u globacom -pglobacom < E:\ravi_globacom\globacom_data4.sql
```

depending on what's most practical.

Comment: It is getting this error   ERROR:
Failed to open file 'E:\ravi_globacom\globacom_data.sql', error: 2

Comment: That's not the same path as in your question.

Comment: no.It is same path I had tried with other .sql files it is working for only this it is not orking

Comment: It is **not** the same path and filename as in your question. If it is working for some files and not others, either you've got permission problems or you're not typing the full path properly.

Comment: same as in the question I had typed but it is showing the problem only for this

Comment: Read my previous comment. The error message is very explicit and simple. Either that file does not exist, or the permissions aren't right. There's nothing a DBA can do for you about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it solved with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBName.* TO 'UserName'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```